# find number in string and replace it with a string from a dictionary in golang

Tags: go, regexp-replace

I am new to Golang; but I have a project that require me to work with Golang.

My Problem: I have an output coming from a variable and that output contains some numbers. those number represent a named instance.

What I am trying to do: To check the output (alertmap) for number and check the number (num_var) found against a dictionary I have created. If a match is found; replace the number (num_var) with the string (value)from the dictionary in the (alertmap).

I have a variable called alertmap that has a key and a value.
The key is what I want to change

```
package main

import (
        "bytes"
        "context"
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "math"
        "net/http"
        "os"
        "strconv"
        "time"
        "errors"
        "regexp"
        "strings"
)


my_dicts = {
123456: "project_data"
2345671: "project_dev-1"
}

func alertme ()
     for key, value := range alertmap
           my_alert += fmt.Sprintln("\n", key, "is a", value.usage, "and Expires in:", value.expireComputed, "days")
                }
```

what I want to do is insert an if statemnet after "for key, value := range alertmap" to check if key(my/123456/secret/salon for example) has a number in it then replace that number with the string that match from the dictionary. key will the be my/project_data/secret/salon (this is what I want sent as key).
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
re := regexp.MustCompile("[0-9]+")

func alertme ()
     for key, value := range alertmap {
           my_alert += fmt.Sprintln("\n", key, "is a", value.usage, "and Expires in:", value.expireComputed, "days")
                }
           // Find value to replace and convert to int
           dictKey, _ := strconv.Atoi(re.FindString(key))
           // Replace value 
           replacedKey := re.ReplaceAllString(key, my_dicts[dictKey])
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @theundeadmonk ; but it seems your solution will replace the entire string. I only want to replace the number. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it out? It will only replace the occurrence of the number in the string.

Comment: I tried; but I am getting ```assignment mismatch: 1 variable but strconv.Atoi returns 2 values```. I am looking it up online and troubleshooting. Also I have to change Atoi to strconv.Atoi for it to actually give me anything. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry. Updated the code.

Comment: Thanks you for your help @theundeadmonk! I got it to work thanks to you. Appreciate it!